# Expand a Tuple Into Semi-Repeating Pairs

Tags: python, functional-programming

I would like to **functionally** derive this input/output pattern:

```
>>> foo( (2, 3, 4, 5) )
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

The idea is that the second element of the previous tuple is repeated as the first element of the next tuple. I can't get it any other way than using iterative paradigms.

For what it's worth, I'm trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447227/area-of-a-polygon-recursively-using-python), and I also have to demonstrate functional Python at a meetup next month. So help me kill two birds with one stone please, and thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> f = (2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> zip(f[:-1], f[1:])
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Or, from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return izip(a, b)
... 
>>> tuple(pairwise(f))
((2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5))
```

Comment: Hey! You already answered the other guy's question! Shoo! `;)`

Comment: @Droogans, lol, sorry -- I didn't realize it was the same one.

Comment: @Droogans, but looking at your comments, I think I see what you're getting at, and I think it's more interesting than my answer anyway (which was more educational than efficient). You should post it anyway.

Comment: Wow...JTLYK, I wrote out a module that *does what their question asked*, but when checking the results, realized that **they posted the incorrect formula**. Oh well, at least I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How about a recursive (and functional!) solution:

```
def foo(t):
    if len(t) < 2:
        return []
    return [(t[0], t[1])] + foo(t[1:])
```

Here's another way to solve it, a bit more efficient since it doesn't create temporary slices of `t` as the above solution:

```
def foo(t):
    limit = len(t) - 2
    def bar(i):
        if i > limit:
            return []
        return [(t[i], t[i+1])] + bar(i+1)
    return bar(0)
```